# Which is suitable db2 version on windows server 2012 server?

Tags: db2, windows-server

I am planning to install db2 database server on my client machine.

So which version of db2 will be more suitable on  windows server 2012 server

> db2 10.1.0

or

> db2 10.5.0

or any other ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd say go with the latest (11.1 as J. Allen recommends) or with N-1, which would be 10.5. This may depend on your company policies, your comfortability with bleeding edge, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

db2 v11.1 was recently released, it works great on a 2012 server.